# Firebase storage rules being ignored with rest api

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I'm using python 2.7 for my frontend, so I'm forced to using rest api to run cloud functions to manage all storage operations.

Right now I'm trying to set basic rules for storage that do the following:

- All users can read
- Only authenticated users with matching uid can write to their appropriate storage

Here's are the storage rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
    }
    match /{userId}/{allPaths=**} {
      allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }
  }
}
```

I noticed that my write rule isn't working, although when using rules playground in the console it verifies and denies as expected.

I hardcoded my cloud function to write into storage with a specific uid in the path, so in theory only that user with the matching uid should be able to write to it. Though if I authenticate with another account it's able to write anyways when it should be getting denied. So why is it ignoring my storage rules?

In Python, I'm calling the endpoint like this:

```
img_url = "C:/Users/USER/pic.jpg"
with open(img_url, "r") as f:
    img_data = f.read().encode("base64")

url = "https://us-central1-[REDACTED].cloudfunctions.net/upload?key={apiKey}".format(apiKey=api_key)
params = {"imgData": img_data, "idToken": id_token, "mediaType": "image/jpeg"}
headers = {"Content-type": "application/json", "Authorization": "Bearer " + id_token}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(params))
print response
```

The response will be `200`, and the file will successfully write even though the id token I pass is for a different user.

Are storage rules ignored if I'm going through rest? Do I need to validate this myself in the cloud function?

If it matters, in the cloud function I'm using `admin.storage.bucket.file.save` to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access the Firebase services with the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin?authuser=0) all the Security Rules are **entirely bypassed**. This is the case with Cloud Functions, which use the Admin SDK.

In other words, Security Rules only apply to web and mobile client "direct" access.

---

So, to answer your questions:

> Are storage rules ignored if I'm going through rest?

Actually you call an [HTTPS Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?authuser=0), which, in turn, interacts with the Cloud Storage service. This is a bit different than "going through the REST API". This is why "storage rules (are) ignored".

> Do I need to validate this myself in the cloud function?

Yes, this is exactly what you need to do. You need to implement your own validation, since, as said above, Security Rules are bypassed.